# Press and hold to copy text within UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, textview, copy, scrollview

I have an app with a `UIScrollView` and within it are several `UITextViews`. I want to make a press and hold function that will copy the text within it.

I have tried several methods, but none of them worked.  Do you have any idea how I can create this action?

Comment: It would be most useful if you show what you've tried and what errors you get, rather than just asking for gimme code.

Comment: Please try to include code you've tried so that others can help you more

Comment: ... and what are these said methods that you've tried?  Please elaborate so we don't unnecessarily suggest something that you've tried.  It won't waste our time as well as yours.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know several methods you tried ?
But you can try

[image]

or set in code

```
yourTextview.selectable = true
```